# Remote taskkill no longer working

Tags: windows

I have a few places where I have a batch file set to run a remote taskkill to kill print spoolers on several servers (mostly 2012R2). This has worked fine until recently. Now, whenever it's run, it prompts for credentials for the remote machines, and when credentials are entered, it fails, indicating incorrect username or password, which is not the case. I did find other similar posts suggesting a UAC remote restrictions, which although I didn't think was the issue because this worked fine until about a month ago, but I tried it, and no change.

Does anyone have any ideas what could have changed out of the blue to stop this from working? It does seem possible that an update may have caused this, but so far, I haven't found anything other than the previously mentioned UAC reg fix.

Comment: Do other kinds of SMB/RPC access to those systems work (e.g. SMB via `dir \\server\c$` or service management via `sc \\server query spooler`) with the exact same credentials? Are you running the script over RDP? Is the script connecting to servers via full name or via IP address? Are you entering the username as `domain\user` or as `user@domain`? Are the servers on a domain that someone else manages?

Comment: The script is being run from a RDP session to the server. 'dir \\server\c$' - yes. 'sc \\server query spooler' - yes. 'full name or via IP address' - short name, but using FQDN provides the same result. When prompted, yes, username is entered as domain\username (same user I'm logged in with which has FULL admin rights everywhere). I manage the domain. Regular command prompt or elevated command prompt makes no difference. It seems ONLY the remote taskkill is not working.

Comment: I think I may have found a possible answer as to why this stopped working. I was doing some more digging and found eventID 10036 with the below information:
"The server-side authentication level policy does not allow the user USERNAME from address x.x.x.x to activate DCOM server. Please raise the activation authentication level at least to RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_INTEGRITY in client application."

Research suggests that it's related one or more updated meant to address 'CVE-2021-26414'. Since that event is logged right after trying to remotely run taskkill...

Comment: Given that this started in June, and the update release from June 2021 added the hardening changes but they were disabled by default, and June 14 2022's release flipped the hardening changes to enabled by default, I'm pretty sure this is the cause.